# How to a condition for temporary column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, ssms

```
USE COLEGIUU
SELECT NmStud, PrenStud, 
      NotaMedie = (SELECT AVG(N.Nota) FROM [Notele] N WHERE N.idStudent = S.IdStudent)
  FROM Student S
  WHERE idStudent IN(SELECT idStudent FROM Notele GROUP BY idStudent)
```

NotaMedie is a temporary column with a calculable values.How can i output only the rows which have NotaMedie > 9 ?

Comment: This does not look like MySQL syntax. Maybe you are running SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can join, aggregate, and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select s.NmStud, s.PrenStud, avg(n.Nota) NotaMedie
from student s
inner join notele n on n.idStudent = s.idStudent
group by s.NmStud, s.PrenStud
having avg(n.Nota) > 9
```